# Calling R Function from C++

Tags: c++, r

I would like to, within my own compiled C++ code, check to see if a library package is loaded in R (if not, load it), call a function from that library and get the results back to in my C++ code.

Could someone point me in the right direction? There seems to be a plethora of info on R and different ways of calling R from C++ and vis versa, but I have not come across exactly what I am wanting to do.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you detail what the plethora is?  There is what the *Writing R Extensions* manual describes, and there are extensions such as  Rcpp/RInside extensions.  What else did you encounter, and why did it not fit the bill?

Answer (score 57):

Dirk's probably right that RInside makes life easier. But for the die-hards... The essence comes from [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html) sections 8.1 and 8.2, and from the examples distributed with R. The material below covers constructing and evaluating the call; dealing with the return value is a different (and in some sense easier) topic.

### Setup

Let's suppose a Linux / Mac platform. The first thing is that R must have been compiled to allow linking, either to a shared or static R library. I work with an svn copy of R's source, in the directory `~/src/R-devel`. I switch to some other directory, call it `~/bin/R-devel`, and then

```
~/src/R-devel/configure --enable-R-shlib
make -j
```

this generates `~/bin/R-devel/lib/libR.so`; perhaps whatever distribution you're using already has this? The `-j` flag runs make in parallel, which greatly speeds the build.

Examples for embedding are in `~/src/R-devel/tests/Embedding`, and they can be made with `cd ~/bin/R-devel/tests/Embedding && make`. Obviously, the source code for these examples is extremely instructive.

### Code

To illustrate, create a file `embed.cpp`. Start by including the header that defines R data structures, and the R embedding interface; these are located in `bin/R-devel/include`, and serve as the primary documentation. We also have a prototype for the function that will do all the work

```
#include <Rembedded.h>
#include <Rdefines.h>

static void doSplinesExample();
```

The work flow is to start R, do the work, and end R:

```
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Rf_initEmbeddedR(argc, argv);
    doSplinesExample();
    Rf_endEmbeddedR(0);
    return 0;
}
```

The examples under `Embedding` include one that calls `library(splines)`, sets a named option, then runs a function `example("ns")`. Here's the routine that does this

```
static void
doSplinesExample()
{
    SEXP e, result;
    int errorOccurred;

    // create and evaluate 'library(splines)'
    PROTECT(e = lang2(install("library"), mkString("splines")));
    R_tryEval(e, R_GlobalEnv, &errorOccurred);
    if (errorOccurred) {
        // handle error
    }
    UNPROTECT(1);

    // 'options(FALSE)' ...
    PROTECT(e = lang2(install("options"), ScalarLogical(0)));
    // ... modified to 'options(example.ask=FALSE)' (this is obscure)
    SET_TAG(CDR(e), install("example.ask"));
    R_tryEval(e, R_GlobalEnv, NULL);
    UNPROTECT(1);

    // 'example("ns")'
    PROTECT(e = lang2(install("example"), mkString("ns")));
    R_tryEval(e, R_GlobalEnv, &errorOccurred);
    UNPROTECT(1);
}
```

### Compile and run

We're now ready to put everything together. The compiler needs to know where the headers and libraries are

```
g++ -I/home/user/bin/R-devel/include -L/home/user/bin/R-devel/lib -lR embed.cpp
```

The compiled application needs to be run in the correct environment, e.g., with R_HOME set correctly; this can be arranged easily (obviously a deployed app would want to take a more extensive approach) with

```
R CMD ./a.out
```

Depending on your ambitions, some parts of section 8 of Writing R Extensions are not relevant, e.g., callbacks are needed to implement a GUI on top of R, but not to evaluate simple code chunks.

### Some detail

Running through that in a bit of detail... An SEXP (S-expression) is a data structure fundamental to R's representation of basic types (integer, logical, language calls, etc.). The line

```
    PROTECT(e = lang2(install("library"), mkString("splines")));
```

makes a symbol `library` and a string `"splines"`, and places them into a language construct consisting of two elements. This constructs an unevaluated language object, approximately equivalent to `quote(library("splines"))` in R. `lang2` returns an SEXP that has been allocated from R's memory pool, and it needs to be `PROTECT`ed from garbage collection. `PROTECT` adds the address pointed to by `e` to a protection stack, when the memory no longer needs to be protected, the address is popped from the stack (with `UNPROTECT(1)`, a few lines down). The line

```
    R_tryEval(e, R_GlobalEnv, &errorOccurred);
```

tries to evaluate `e` in R's global environment. `errorOccurred` is set to non-0 if an error occurs. `R_tryEval` returns an SEXP representing the result of the function, but we ignore it here. Because we no longer need the memory allocated to store `library("splines")`, we tell R that it is no longer PROTECT'ed.

The next chunk of code is similar, evaluating `options(example.ask=FALSE)`, but the construction of the call is more complicated. The S-expression created by `lang2` is a *pair list*, conceptually with a node, a left pointer (CAR) and a right pointer (CDR). The left pointer of `e` points to the symbol `options`. The right pointer of `e` points to another node in the pair list, whose left pointer is `FALSE` (the right pointer is `R_NilValue`, indicating the end of the language expression). Each node of a pair list can have a `TAG`, the meaning of which depends on the role played by the node. Here we attach an argument name.

```
    SET_TAG(CDR(e), install("example.ask"));
```

The next line evaluates the expression that we have constructed (`options(example.ask=FALSE)`), using `NULL` to indicate that we'll ignore the success or failure of the function's evaluation. A different way of constructing and evaluating this call is illustrated in `R-devel/tests/Embedding/RParseEval.c`, adapted here as

```
PROTECT(tmp = mkString("options(example.ask=FALSE)"));
PROTECT(e = R_ParseVector(tmp, 1, &status, R_NilValue));
R_tryEval(VECTOR_ELT(e, 0), R_GlobalEnv, NULL);
UNPROTECT(2);
```

but this doesn't seem like a good strategy in general, as it mixes R and C code and does not allow computed arguments to be used in R functions. Instead write and manage R code in R (e.g., creating a package with functions that perform complicated series of R manipulations) that your C code uses.

The final block of code above constructs and evaluates `example("ns")`. `Rf_tryEval` returns the result of the function call, so

```
SEXP result;
PROTECT(result = Rf_tryEval(e, R_GlobalEnv, &errorOccurred));
// ...
UNPROTECT(1);
```

would capture that for subsequent processing.

Answer (score 43):

There is [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) which allows you to easily extend R with C++ code, and also have that C++ code call back to R. There are examples included in the package which show that.

But maybe what you really want is to keep your C++ program (i.e. you own `main()`) and call out to R?  That can be done most easily with 
[RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) which allows you to very easily embed R inside your C++ application---and the test for library, load if needed and function call are then extremely easy to do, and the (more than a dozen) included examples show you how to.  And [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) still helps you to get results back and forth.

**Edit:** As Martin was kind enough to show things *the official way* I cannot help and contrast it with one of the examples shipping with RInside. It is something I once wrote quickly to help someone who had asked on r-help about how to load (a portfolio optimisation) library and use it.  It meets your requirements: load a library, accesses some data in pass a weights vector down from C++ to R, deploy R and get the result back.

```
// -*- mode: C++; c-indent-level: 4; c-basic-offset: 4;  tab-width: 8; -*-
//
// Simple example for the repeated r-devel mails by Abhijit Bera
//
// Copyright (C) 2009         Dirk Eddelbuettel 
// Copyright (C) 2010 - 2011  Dirk Eddelbuettel and Romain Francois

#include <RInside.h>                    // for the embedded R via RInside

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    try {
        RInside R(argc, argv);          // create an embedded R instance 

        std::string txt = "suppressMessages(library(fPortfolio))";
        R.parseEvalQ(txt);              // load library, no return value

        txt = "M <- as.matrix(SWX.RET); print(head(M)); M";
        // assign mat. M to NumericMatrix
        Rcpp::NumericMatrix M = R.parseEval(txt); 

        std::cout << "M has " 
                  << M.nrow() << " rows and " 
                  << M.ncol() << " cols" << std::endl;

        txt = "colnames(M)";        // assign columns names of M to ans and
        // into string vector cnames
        Rcpp::CharacterVector cnames = R.parseEval(txt);   

        for (int i=0; i<M.ncol(); i++) {
            std::cout << "Column " << cnames[i] 
                      << " in row 42 has " << M(42,i) << std::endl;
        }

    } catch(std::exception& ex) {
        std::cerr << "Exception caught: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    } catch(...) {
        std::cerr << "Unknown exception caught" << std::endl;
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

This `rinside_sample2.cpp`, and there are lots more examples in the package.   To build it, you just say 'make rinside_sample2' as the supplied `Makefile` is set up to find R, Rcpp and RInside.

Comment: +1 I was under the impression that Rcpp did the embedding part too. Deleted my answer since your's is clearly superior.

Comment: Rcpp lets you access functions etc, but if you're coming from a standalone C++ program, you don't actually have an R process. The R Embedding API provides that, and RInside makes it a easier to use by abstracting a lot of the details away.