# Is there a way to call R from a standalone C++ program without the need to disclose the source

Tags: c++, r

we think about using a statistical library package in our application and want to know whether it is possible to use R without having to publish the source of our application.

Thank you.
Tobias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should definitively ask a lawyer (or maybe someone from an intellectual property department).

However, here are my 2 ct:

- It should be possible the same way that also allows writing closed-source programs for Linux.
- A solution that very much emphasizes the fact that you are talking about 2 programs, R and yours, would be using an R server
- Wikipedia summarizes a discussion about [whether linking implies the result is a derived work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License#Linking_and_derived_works).
  Not astonishingly, FSF's point of view is that it is irrelevant whether the linking is dynamic or static. After all, they say if linking of a program with a non-free (incompatible) licence to the free library should be allowed, the license of the library should be LGPL instead of GPL. However, the Wiki article gives other points of view as well.

Here are 2 relevant snippets from the GPL FAQ:

- > **[What is the difference between an “aggregate” and other kinds of “modified versions”?](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#MereAggregation)**
  >
  > An “aggregate” consists of a number of separate programs, distributed together on the same CD-ROM or other media. The GPL permits you to create and distribute an aggregate, even when the licenses of the other software are non-free or GPL-incompatible. The only condition is that you cannot release the aggregate under a license that prohibits users from exercising rights that each program's individual license would grant them.
  >
  > Where's the line between two separate programs, and one program with two parts? This is a legal question, which ultimately judges will decide. [...]
  >
  > If the modules are included in the same executable file, they are definitely combined in one program. If modules are designed to run linked together in a shared address space, that almost surely means combining them into one program.
  >
  > **By contrast, pipes, sockets and command-line arguments are communication mechanisms normally used between two separate programs. So when they are used for communication, the modules normally are separate programs.** But if the semantics of the communication are intimate enough, exchanging complex internal data structures, that too could be a basis to consider the two parts as combined into a larger program.
- > **[I'd like to incorporate GPL-covered software in my proprietary system. Can I do this?](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLInProprietarySystem)**
  >
  > You cannot incorporate GPL-covered software in a proprietary system. [...]
  >
  > However, **in many cases you can distribute the GPL-covered software alongside your proprietary system. To do this validly, you must make sure that the free and non-free programs communicate at arms length, that they are not combined in a way that would make them effectively a single program.**
  >
  > The difference between this and “incorporating” the GPL-covered software is partly a matter of substance and partly form. The substantive part is this: if the two programs are combined so that they become effectively two parts of one program, then you can't treat them as two separate programs. So the GPL has to cover the whole thing.
  >
  > If the two programs remain well separated, like the compiler and the kernel, or like an editor and a shell, then you can treat them as two separate programs—but you have to do it properly. [...]

Comment: the question here is - is it possible as in: can I dynamically link to R and are the required headers under an appropriate license (some are lgpl, others are gpl). The example provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457635/calling-r-function-from-c?rq=1 uses headers that are explicitly not under LGPL.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I believe that the GPL only applies to software that you distribute.  It is perfectly legal to develop a closed source program that incorporates GPL code so long as you do not distribute it.  I'm not sure what exactly constitutes distribution in this sense, however (for example, is it distribution when another party accesses your web application?).

Comment: @Iron Savior: you are right, but this simple fact does not solve my problem

Comment: @TobiasLangner Dynamic linking to GPL code amounts to incorporating it into your program.  IANAL, but my understanding is if the original code is licensed under the LGPL, then dynamic linking by a closed source program is allowed but not if the code is licensed under GPL.

Comment: Clarification:  I believe that if any program links to any GPL-licensed code, then all of that program must be open source in a way that is compatible with the full GPL--so that would prevent you from making a LGPL "bridge" between closed source and GPL code.  (IANAL, of course)

Comment: @IronSavior: Wikipedia has a summary of this discussion, I added a link to that. Also, the GPL FAQ has several places where it explicitly says that dynamic linking of plugins for GPL programs means that the plugin must have a compatible license.

Comment: To sum it up: since GPL is unclear on what condition a program is derivative work it is not possible to use R in non open source applications since you could always argue that the information exchange is too intimate to be 2 separate programs.

Comment: @TobiasLangner: that is not true. The GPL FAQ (snippet above) explicitly gives examples how your (non-GPL) program can exchange  information with R without violating the GPL. And, of course, GPL is no exclusive license. Thus, you could ask the copyright holders of R for a license that allows dynamic linking to be on the safe side.

Comment: @cbeleites: the discussion you kindly linked above states the following: it depends on the intimacy of the information exchange. Since there is no technical detail to distinguish whether it is legal to use or not, the risk is too high to use it.