# How to calculate the cumulative density function of a sum of random variables in C++?

Tags: c++, statistics, numerical-methods

I have a number of random variables with known, but possibly different probability distributions (PDFs). I need to calculate the value of the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of the **sum** of these random variables, at a specific point *x*.

This involves two steps:

1. Calculate the convolution of the random variable PDFs in order to get the PDF of
   their sum
2. Calculate CDF(x), i.e. the integral of the summary PDF from *-infinity* to *x*

It looks like the second step can be done only with numerical methods. The first step can be done analytically in some, but not all cases.

For example, if I have one random variable distributed log-normally with PDF:

```
PDF_1(x) = e^(-(log(x) -μ)^2/(2 sigma^2))/(sqrt(2 π) x sigma)
```

and another random variable also  distributed log-normally, but with a different parameter:

```
PDF_2(x) = e^(-(log(x) -μ)^2/(2 delta^2))/(sqrt(2 π) x delta)
```

then the PDF of their sum (`Convolution[PDF_1, PDF_2]`) cannot be calculated analytically.

Assuming arbitrary cut-off point of the tail of the distribution at 1000, and assuming the parameters μ, sigma amd delta are known:

```
PDF_sum(x) = NumericallyIntegrate (PDF_1(y) PDF_2(y - x) dy), y=0 to 1000
```

Now:

```
CDF(x) = NumericallyIntegrate (PDF_sum(y) dy), y=0 to x
```

How to write down this code for the CDF calculation in C++, and what libraries you suggest?

Comment: If you haven't done it yet, please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Use a language which is designed for these types of problem, and interface it with c++. You mentioned `R`. Look at this question : [Calling R Function from C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457635/calling-r-function-from-c)

Comment: Everybody jumped on the bandwagon to mark this as a duplicate, but the supposed duplicate is only remotely similar. Is there any way to get it unmarked and reopened?

Comment: About computing the convolution numerically, it might be convenient to discretize the two pdf's, compute their fast Fourier transforms, compute the product of the FFT's, then compute the inverse FFT to get a discretized version of the convolution. Then the cdf is just the summation of the discretized convolution. (Recall FFT(convolution(f, g)) = FFT(f) times FFT(g).)