# Zero based arrays/vectors in R

Tags: r, indexing

Is there some way to make R use zero based indexing for vectors and other sequence data structures as is followed,  for example in  C and python.

We have some code that does some numerical processing in C,  we are thinking of  porting it over into R to make use of its advanced statistical functions,  but the lack(as per my understanding after googling) of zero based index makes the task a bit more difficult.

Comment: No, there isn't. Why would you expect there to be? You can't make C or python use one-based indexing. I guess you could write custom indexing methods, but that seems like a lot of work to avoid a little care while translating C to R. Why don't you just call portions of the C code from R?

Comment: try the [Oarray package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Oarray/index.html)

Comment: Also, your R code will have serious performance issues if you simply only do what's necessary to translate your C syntax to R syntax. Instead, you should convert the logic in your C program to fit the R paradigm.

Comment: I agree with @JoshuaUlrich Instead of "porting it over into R to make use of its advanced statistical functions" [call the R functions in your C code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7457635/1412059).

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich AFAIK it is not unknown for languages to support both zero based and one based indexing,  like pascal http://www.tutorialspoint.com/pascal/pascal_arrays.htm.

Comment: Point taken, but still, why would you expect it to be possible if it's not explicitly stated that it's possible?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I understand now that it is not something that is not really possible in  R,  only  I was curious that there might be some way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR: just don't do it!**

I don't think the zero/one-based indexing is a major obstacle in porting your C code to R. 
However, if you truly believe that it is necessary to do so, you can certainly override the `.Primitive('[')` function, changing the behavior of the indexing/subsetting in R.

```
# rename the original `[`
> index1 <- .Primitive('[')

# WICKED!: override `[`. 
> `[` <- function(v, i) index1(v, i+1)
> x <- 1:5
> x[0]
[1] 1
> x[1]
[1] 2
> x[0:2]
[1] 1 2 3
```

However, this can be seriously dangerous because you changed the fundamental indexing behavior and can cause unexpected cascading effects for all libraries and functions that utilizes subsetting and indexing.

For example, because subsetting and indexing can accept other type of data as a selector (boolean vector, say), and the simple overriding function doesn't take that into account, you can have very strange behavior:

```
> x[x > 2] # x > 2 returns a boolean vector, and by + 1, you convert 
           # boolean FALSE/TRUE to numeric 0/1
[1] 1 1 2 2 2
```

Although this can be addressed by modifying the overriding function, you still may have other issues.

Another example:

```
> (idx <- which(x > 2)) # which() still gives you 1-based index
> x[idx]
[1]  4  5 NA
```

You never know where things might go wrong horribly. So, just don't.

Comment: I get your point that it is better not to attempt it,  but I do wonder that the base of the index is hardwired so thoroughly,  that it cannot be changed without serious ramifications.

Comment: You meant, in your C code? Just pay extra attention to all the indexing when you are doing the porting and you should be fine.

Comment: No,  I did not mean my  C code,  but I was talking of the implementation of R.

Answer (score 6):

I want to develop Xin Yin's answer.
It's possible to define new class (like `zero-based_vector`), method `[` for this class and then assign this class to attributes of target vectors.

```
# define new method for our custom class 
index1 <- .Primitive('[')
`[.zero-based_vector` <- function(v, i) index1(as.vector(v), i+1)

x <- letters
# make `x` a zero-bazed_vector 
class(x) <- c("zero-based_vector", class(x))
# it works!
x[0:3]
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

By the way, nothing will be broken, because we don't override `.Primitive('[')`

Answer (score 1):

You can make "auxiliary" indexes for more convenient work with 0-based constructions in R.

Here is the idea. Suppose we need to calculate y(x) = x^2 over integer x in [0; 10]:

```
x <- 0:10 # 0 based index for calculations
y <- c()
y[x+1] <- x^2 # have to add 1 when indexing y

x. <- x+1 # auxiliary 1 based index for R vectors indexing    
y <- c()
y[x.] <- x^2 # no need to remember to add 1
```

Just pick up naming pattern for auxiliary indexes that suits you: it could be x1 or x_1 - and train yourself to use it whenever you write square brackets.  I decided to use the dot because it is big enough to be perceptible, but not too big to make the code messy, in my opinion.

The example above is simple, but if we need to do more complicated variable transformations like [image: y_i = x_{i+1}*a^{i+1} + x_i*a^i] (for i in [0; 10]) then taking care about additional indexes pays for itself:

```
i <- 0:10
y[i+1] <- x[i+2]*a^(i+1) + x[i+1]*a^i # does not resemble 
                                      # the original formula

i. <- i+1
y[i.] <- x[i.+1]*a^(i+1) + x[i.]*a^i # Now it is easier to see the
                                     # original formula behind this
```

As you can see the code becomes clearer making it easier to compare it to the original formula when examining the code for mistakes.

Comment: Should it be `y[i+1] <- x[i+2]*a^(i+2) + x[i+1]*a^(i+1) # does not resemble the original formula` and `y[i.] <- x[i.+1]*a^(i.+1) + x[i.]*a^i. # Now it is easier to see the original formula behind this`? Why didn't you apply the logic to a to the power part?

Answer (score 0):

If for example you want instead matrix indices (1..3, 1..3) have indices (0..2, 0..2) for your matrix G and you want to read entries like G(0,2) and put entries like G(0,2) = 5 then one can use the following workaround:

```
GG      = matrix( (1:9)*0, 3, 3);
G       = function(i,j, x){
             if (missing(x)){
                return(GG[i+1, j+1]);
             }
             CC = GG;
             CC[i+1, j+1] = x;
             GG <<- CC; }

>G(0,2,5)  # for manipulate G on position (0,2) (or GG on position (1,3))               
           # and set the entry to value equal 5
> GG;
        [,1] [,2] [,3]
  [1,]    0    0    5
  [2,]    0    0    0
  [3,]    0    0    0
> G(0,2); 
[1] 5
```

Here G(0,2,5) is like G(0,2) = 5 and if you type G(0,2) you get the entry 5 which means you can make calculations like erg = G(0,2) + 3. 
In order to use indices starting with 0 instead with 1 you just shift the indices by 1 and use an auxiliary matrix GG.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  It would be helpful to give a quick explanation with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be the following (here an example for an 3x3-matrix):

```
n         = 3;
GG        = matrix( (1:(n+1)^2)*0, n+1, n+1);

cl        = 0;

G         = function(i,j){ return(GG[i+1, j+1]) } 

':='      = function(GAuf,x){

       cl <<- match.call();
       aa = deparse(cl$GAuf);
       d1 = gregexpr(pattern="\\(", aa)
       d2 = gregexpr(pattern=",", aa)
       s1 = d1[[1]][1] + 1;
       s2 = d2[[1]][1] - 1;
       i  = substr(aa, s1, s2);
       d1 = gregexpr(pattern=" ", aa)
       d2 = gregexpr(pattern=")", aa)
       s1 = d1[[1]][1]+1;
       s2 = d2[[1]][1]-1;
       j  = substr(aa, s1, s2);
       d  = gregexpr(pattern="\\(", aa);
       s  = d[[1]][1]-1;
       fn = substr(aa, 1, s);

       com= paste(fn,fn, "[", i,"+1,", j,"+1]","<<-x", sep="");

       eval(parse(text=com));
```

}

Now you can set a value by

```
G(0,1) := 2
```

and get the value by

```
> G(0,1)
```

[1] 2

Note that I used the convention that if you use a matrix named 'N' then the function ':=' expects a matrix named 'NN' (here matrix 'G' and 'GG') as you can see at the end of the function ':=' because the string 'com' is set by 'paste(fn,fn,...)'. If you want to name your matrix "hello" then you have to define a matrix "hellohello" (like matrix 'GG') and a matrix "hello" (like matrix 'G').