# How to set a numeric vector of length 0 to just 0?

Tags: r, indexing

I have a function where in some iterations I come into situation where I have to return a value of a function at 0 position which returns

```
funX[0] = numeric(0) `
```

I understand that, R indexing starts from 1. However, if I could convert these outputs to just simply zero, life would have been easier. I do not find a way around.

Is there any way where such returns would simply be converted as 0?

Addition: I tried to set funX[0] <- 0L in the beginning of the function but it doesn't work.

Comment: No, there's nothing automatic, but there's lots of catches you could implement, easiest probably being just return the index itself if `i == 0`, otherwise return `funX[i]`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25307549/zero-based-arrays-vectors-in-r